# javascript: how to read this and is it compatible across browsers

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

The following variable assignment works in javascript and assigns the value 5 to x.

```
const x = (1,2,3,4,5);
```

How to read this? Why is javascript assigning last value in the list to x and will this work across browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard behavior, and should be cross-browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 0):

Comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

That is why in your example 5 is being assigned to the variable x.

This is the standard behaviour across all browsers.